# Rewrite URL (htaccess)

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

how can I rewrite the following URL schema http://www.example.com/blog/xyz to http://www.example.com/blog/#xyz?

Comment: Did my answer help you? If yes, could you please accept it for future users with the same question?

Comment: No sorry, it works not in Wordpress.

Comment: What exactly is your goal with this rewriterule? Do you want to go to the index page of the blogs and then have the window to scroll to the right blog?

Comment: I use in Wordpress a One Page/Single Page. All my Pages are listed at one page. So I need a url rewrite which makes NO reload! It should link to the anchor (on this page).

Comment: My navigation makes following urls: localhost/blog/xyz but it should make this urls: localhost/blog/#xyz

Comment: with the reriterule I wrote, `localhost/blog/xyz` will actually be `localhost/blog/#xyz`. If I get you correctly, you want to scroll automatically to the right blog on the page when you click on a link?

Comment: Yes, that right. I will try it again.

Comment: I don't think this'll work. The browser scrolls down to the right element with the `id` behind the `#`, and if you use a rewriterule, the browser won't see the `#`

Comment: But there must be a solution? How set other Developer this for One Page Sites in Wordpress?

Comment: You might be able to do it with javascript, but I can't help you with that since I'm no javascript expert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this (don't forget the `NE` flag):

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteRule ^blog/([^#]+)$ blog/#$1 [L,NE]
```